# Nodejs breeze-sequelize with MySQL - .select() not functioning

Tags: mysql, node.js, breeze

I'm using breeze-sequelize version 0.0.18. I get a bizarre error `_.pluck is not a function` when I try to use select() on the entityQuery. And if I remove .select(), it'll work just fine.

My breeze query looks like this:

```
var predicate = Predicate.create('transactionDate', '>=', fromDate);
var entityQuery = EntityQuery.from('Transactions')
  .where(predicate)
  .select('transactionDate');
var sequelizeQuery = new SequelizeQuery(api.db, entityQuery);
return sequelizeQuery.execute();
```

And upon return, the error I get is:

```
TypeError: _.pluck is not a function
at SequelizeQuery.<anonymous> (/Users/shu/Documents/project/node_modules/breeze-sequelize/SequelizeQuery.json.js:143:39)
at Array.map (native)
at SequelizeQuery._processSelect (/Users/shu/Documents/project/node_modules/breeze-sequelize/SequelizeQuery.json.js:136:56)
at SequelizeQuery._processQuery (/Users/shu/Documents/project/node_modules/breeze-sequelize/SequelizeQuery.json.js:72:8)
at new SequelizeQuery (/Users/shu/Documents/project/node_modules/breeze-sequelize/SequelizeQuery.json.js:43:23)
at getTransactions (/Users/shu/Documents/project/src/server/api/admin.controller.js:189:26)
```

So curiously I took a look at function `SequelizeQuery._processSelect` in my breeze-sequelize library. The error is coming from `return usesNameOnServer ?  pp : _.pluck(props, "nameOnServer").join(".");`.

```
SequelizeQuery.prototype._processSelect = function() {
var selectClause = this.entityQuery.selectClause;
  var usesNameOnServer = this.entityQuery.usesNameOnServer;
  if (selectClause == null) return;
  // extract any nest paths and move them onto the include
  var navPropertyPaths = [];
  this.sqQuery.attributes = selectClause.propertyPaths.map(function(pp) {
    var props = this.entityType.getPropertiesOnPath(pp, usesNameOnServer, true);
    var isNavPropertyPath = props[0].isNavigationProperty;
    if (isNavPropertyPath) {
      this._addInclude(this.sqQuery, props);
    }
    if (isNavPropertyPath) return null;
    return usesNameOnServer ?  pp : _.pluck(props, "nameOnServer").join(".");
  }, this).filter(function(pp) {
    return pp != null;
  });
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_.pluck` function is from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck), and lodash removed the `pluck` function in version 4.0

The breeze-sequelize library will eventually be updated to lodash 4, but in the meantime, try using lodash 3.x.